What is "two letter identification code" and how is this code sent as a signal with light by flashing?
What is "two letter identification code" and how is this code sent as a signal with light by flashing?

What is the source of the quoted text, please?   Sounds almost like a visual version of the old A-N range, which haven't been used in a long, long time.

This quote is from the mid-ACE document, which is a summary of the ACE (Airline Pilot Interview Questions) resource. Whole article on the subject: Two types of beacon: Identification Beacon and the Location Beacon. An Identification Beacon flashing a two letter identification code in green. Where the aerodrome is also situated well away from areas of high background lighting, the Location Beacon would display a flashing White light. Where the aerodrome is situated in an area where there is a high level of background lighting, such as in the vicinity of a city...

...where a flashing white light would be difficult to see, the Location Beacon would display a green light flashing alternately with a white light.

Is there any reason to believe it would not be Morse code?

Previously answered (the two beacons, identifying vs. non identifying, morse code) in: What is a "BEACON"?. This is also part of CAP 637 for UK.
